# Lagrange Polynomial Interpolation in O(n) Time

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

Is it possible to evaluate a Lagrange polynomial interpolation in O(n) time after using a preprocessing step with O(n^2) operations? Thank you.

Comment: This is described in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) under Barycentric form (I apologize for not providing the sub page link but I’m on mobile).